# Getting iCloud items with UIImagePickerController fails in iOS9

Tags: ios, icloud

I have a code like this for getting a video from the Library, and it was working perfectly on iOS 8.x but it fails in `iOS9` when you are getting an item which is on the cloud (and is not downloaded yet).

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
  if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie]) {
    NSURL *url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

On `iOS8` the image picker shows "compressing video" progress bar after selecting video, and then after finishing that the control gets back to my app.

When it fails on iOS9, the "compressing video" bar disappears immediately and the control gets back to my app at the same time.  In this case,
`UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` value gets nil and consequently getting the asset fails.

Then my questions are: 
(1)Are there any official mentions about this change of behavior?
(2)If it's an intentional change what is the right way to get the assets?

Any info is appreciated.

Thanks

// Takeshi

Comment: It seems like getting the media with UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL already discouraged...? 

I found that the info dictionary from the picker always contains UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL  so I added an if-branch so you use  UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL if exists and use UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL if not.

But I still don't know if it's the best way.

Comment: You should probably file a radar for this. There are quite a few issues when integrating anything involving cloud syncing data. Especially Apple music (don't get me started on how the media picker allows selection of music that you can't do anything to without being able to filter it out from selection).

Comment: Easiest and best work around is to directly use PhotoKit. You've pretty much avoided all unexpected issues at that point and have access to the Photo Objects and their respective states/details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to get videos stored on iCloud as NSData.
It uses the Photos framework as ALAssetLibrary is deprecated as of iOS9:

> IMPORTANT
>
> The Assets Library framework is deprecated as of iOS 9.0. Instead, use the Photos framework instead, which in iOS 8.0 and later provides more features and better performance for working with a user’s photo library. For more information, see Photos Framework Reference.

```
import Photos

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    
    if let referenceURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([referenceURL], options: nil)
        if let phAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(phAsset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
                if let asset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                    let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: asset.URL)
                    
                    // optionally, write the video to the temp directory
                    let videoPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "tmpMovie.MOV"
                    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
                    let writeResult = videoData?.writeToURL(videoURL, atomically: true)
                    
                    if let writeResult = writeResult where writeResult {
                        print("success")
                    }
                    else {
                        print("failure")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```